# Stylus Not Defined After Successful npm install

Tags: javascript, node.js, stylus

I'm attempting to follow along with a tutorial and learn a bit about node.js. I keep getting a weird error, though. After `npm install stylus`, I get this:

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/stylus
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/stylus
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cssom
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/sax
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/debug
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/cssom
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/sax
stylus@0.41.0 node_modules/stylus
├── debug@0.7.4
├── mkdirp@0.3.5
├── cssom@0.2.5
└── sax@0.5.5
```

No errors, nothing warning me of the world's end, not even any red text. Then when I try to run the application `node app.js` I get `ReferenceError: stylus is not defined` on this line:

```
app.use(stylus.middleware(
{
    src: __dirname + '/public'
    , compile: compile
}
))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`npm install` just create JS files on disk.

You still need to call `require()` to load the file and create a local variable:

```
var stylus = require('stylus');
```

Comment: Gah. I had var `stylue = require('stylus')` and didn't catch it. Problem solved, thanks!